# Is there a faster way for finding the range of constant values in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I want to find the longest duration of the constant values in a dataframe. For example, given a dataframe below, the longest duration should be 30 minutes (when value = 2).

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'date_time': ['2016-01-01 12:00:00', '2016-01-01 12:15:00',
       '2016-01-01 12:30:00', '2016-01-01 12:45:00',
       '2016-01-01 13:00:00', '2016-01-01 13:15:00',
       '2016-01-01 13:30:00', '2016-01-01 13:45:00'], 
     'value': [1,2,2,2,4,5,5,7]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'])

print(df)
            date_time  value
0 2016-01-01 12:00:00      1
1 2016-01-01 12:15:00      2
2 2016-01-01 12:30:00      2
3 2016-01-01 12:45:00      2
4 2016-01-01 13:00:00      4
5 2016-01-01 13:15:00      5
6 2016-01-01 13:30:00      5
7 2016-01-01 13:45:00      7
```

(Note: the date_time interval is not always consistent.)

I managed to find it by finding the indexes of `df.value.diff().abs()==0`, build a complex function to iterate through that list and compute the range.

Since the actual dataframe is much larger than this example, is there a shortcut function or a faster way to get this without multiple iterations?

Thank you.

EDIT:

In my case, the same value can appear in other streaks. A more appropriate example would be

```
d = {'date_time': ['2016-01-01 12:00:00', '2016-01-01 12:15:00',
       '2016-01-01 12:30:00', '2016-01-01 12:45:00',
       '2016-01-01 13:00:00', '2016-01-01 13:15:00',
       '2016-01-01 13:30:00', '2016-01-01 13:45:00',
       '2016-01-01 14:00:00', '2016-01-01 14:05:00'], 
     'value': [1,2,2,2,4,5,5,7,5,5]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'])

print(df)

            date_time  value
0 2016-01-01 12:00:00      1
1 2016-01-01 12:15:00      2
2 2016-01-01 12:30:00      2
3 2016-01-01 12:45:00      2
4 2016-01-01 13:00:00      4
5 2016-01-01 13:15:00      5
6 2016-01-01 13:30:00      5
7 2016-01-01 13:45:00      7
8 2016-01-01 14:00:00      5
9 2016-01-01 14:05:00      5
```

The longest duration, in this case, remains 30 minutes when value = 2.

Comment: @KarlThornton The same value can appear again in another streak and that would be a different streak already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can groupby the value column and use `.size()` to get the size/length of each group.

```
>>> groups = df.groupby('value')
>>> groups.size()
value
1    1
2    3
4    1
5    2
7    1
dtype: int64
```

`.idxmax()` will give you the index of the largest group which you can pass to `.get_groups()`

```
>>> groups.get_group(groups.size().idxmax())
             date_time  value
1  2016-01-01 12:15:00      2
2  2016-01-01 12:30:00      2
3  2016-01-01 12:45:00      2
```

Then you can diff the last and first dates (assuming they are sorted - if not you can sort them)

```
>>> max_streak = groups.get_group(groups.size().idxmax())
>>> max_streak.iloc[-1].date_time - max_streak.iloc[0].date_time
Timedelta('0 days 00:30:00')
```

If `value` can repeat in other streaks you can groupby using:

```
groups = df.groupby((df.value != df.value.shift()).cumsum())
```

**Update**: Maximum duration of any streak

```
>>> groups = df.groupby((df.value != df.value.shift()).cumsum())
>>> last = groups.last()
>>> max_duration = (last.date_time - groups.first().date_time).nlargest(1)
>>> max_duration.iat[0]
Timedelta('0 days 00:30:00')
>>> last.loc[max_duration.index].value.iat[0]
2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It was more holistic than my question. The .shift() and cumsum technique works perfectly for my case.

Answer (score 2):

#### `groupby` + `nlargest`

Create a grouping series that tracks changes.

```
groupr = df.value.ne(df.value.shift()).cumsum()
```

Create a mapping dictionary that can translate from the `groupr` key to the actual `value` in the `df.value` column.

```
mapper = dict(zip(groupr, df.value))
```

Now we group and use `ptp` and `nlargest`.  Finally, we use `rename` and `mapper` to translate the `index` value, which is the `groupr` value, back to the `value` value (phew, that's a tad confusing).

```
df.groupby(groupr).date_time.apply(np.ptp).nlargest(1).rename(mapper)

value
2   0 days 00:30:00
Name: date_time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

The `2` in the index is the `value` with the longest duration.  The `0 days 00:30:00` is the longest duration.

#### References

[np.ptp](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ptp.html)
[nlargest](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html)

Comment: Thank you. I like that your answer gives both the value and the duration. However, it does not apply when the value appears again in another streak. Please see my updated example. I would appreciate it if you can update your answer. Thank you:)

Comment: See if that makes sense to you.

Comment: It returns the correct result now. But the "apply" seems to take very long on my actual data frame which is much much larger. I wonder if there is a faster solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use pd.pivot_table to get the minimum and maximum datetime value for each value, then calculate the duration between them and extract the longest.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'date_time': ['2016-01-01 12:00:00', '2016-01-01 12:15:00',
       '2016-01-01 12:30:00', '2016-01-01 12:45:00',
       '2016-01-01 13:00:00', '2016-01-01 13:15:00',
       '2016-01-01 13:30:00', '2016-01-01 13:45:00'], 
     'value': [1,2,2,2,4,5,5,7]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'])

df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, index='value', values='date_time', aggfunc=[np.min,np.max])

df_pivot['duration'] = df_pivot.iloc[:, 1] - df_pivot.iloc[:, 0]

print(df_pivot[df_pivot['duration'] == max(df_pivot['duration'])])
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not express my question clearly. Please see my updated example. The value actually can appear in other streaks, but that shouldn't be counted. Thank you.